# Ошибка при компиляции. Как исправить?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android Studio Arctic Fox. Создаю новый проект Empty Activity. Запускаю. И получаю ошибку:

```
One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Ura\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\9079c9694b4d4270d7cd62242948af25\transformed\appcompat-1.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
```

До этого всё работало.
Если открываю старые проекты всё работает. Но если пытаюсь создать новый получаю эту ошибку.
Файл gradle выглядит так

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.medinq.myclock"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Подскажите, как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: а текст ошибки вы читать умеете? Там же все предельно ясно написано.

Comment: minsdk <= targetSdk <= compileSdk

Comment: @Эникейщик,  прочёл. Зашёл в файл aar-metadata.properties и исправил minCompileSdk=31 на новое значение minCompileSdk=30. Запустил компиляцию и получил тоже самое предупреждение.

Comment: @Wlad, так у меня minsdk = 21, targetSdk = 30, compileSdk = 30. Вроде всё правильно

Comment: Конечно то же самое. Надо менять свой gradle, а не чужую библиотеку.

Comment: @Эникейщик, У меня точно такой же gradle в старых программах работает нормально. А теперь не работает

Comment: А androidx.appcompat там такой же версии?

Comment: @Эникейщик, я ничего не менял. Поэтому не пойму в чём ошибка. Загружаю старую программу - работает. Создаю новую - не работает. Если в gradle меняю targetSdk = 31 и CompileSdk = 31, то всё работает. Но почему раньше всё работало, а теперь нет?

Comment: Видимо, в старой стоит ещё зависимость со старой версией AndroidX, а в новой ставится новая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установить как `compileSdkVersion`, так и `targetSdkVersion`, в 31 в вашем `build.gradle(app)` файле:

```
android { 
    compileSdkVersion 31 //Здесь

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.medinq.myclock"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdkVersion 31 //И здесь
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    } 
}
```